# What is the best way to use multiple akka scheduler each calling different methods?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a scenario where I want to schedule many methods.
I came up with something like this:

```
val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")

system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 5 minutes)(println("this is method 1"))
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 5 minutes)(println("this is method 2"))
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 5 minutes)(println("this is method 3"))`
```

This compiles and executes without problem, but I don't know if it is the best way to schedule multiple methods, because I am using multiple schedulers with the same actor system instance.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "using multiple schedulers"

> Sometimes the need for making things happen in the future arises, and
>   where do you go look then? Look no further than ActorSystem! There you
>   find the scheduler method that returns an instance of
>   akka.actor.Scheduler, **this instance is unique per ActorSystem** and is
>   used internally for scheduling things to happen at specific points in
>   time.
>
> You can schedule sending of messages to actors and execution of tasks
>   (functions or Runnable). You will get a Cancellable back that you can
>   call cancel on to cancel the execution of the scheduled operation.

Source: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/scheduler.html

Since the instance is unique, it should solve your query.

Comment: By "using multiple schedulers" i meant that i wanted to continuously run 3-4 functions with certain intervals inside the same application.
Yes , I understand that the instance of akka.actor.Scheduler is unique per ActorSystem. But what i meant was the instance for ActorSystem is itself not unique i.e the "val system" in the above example. We are using the the same "system" to get the instance of multiple schedulers. So, wont that cause a problem ? 
Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: No. It should not cause a problem. Each time the same instance of scheduler will be returned.